# Communicate with IBM AS400 using FTP/C#/BizTalk

Tags: c#-4.0, biztalk, ibm-midrange

I have to communicate with IBM AS400 system using FTP. Need to issue more than just get and put commands. Essentially need to submit jobs to AS400 using QUOTE RCMD SBMJOB command that will ask AS400 to run some of its programs.

I have two options for communication platform (a) use C# and (b) use BizTalk's FTP adapter.

For C# I have looked at MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229718) but do not see how jobs can be submitted as limited FTP commands are exposed.

For BizTalk Adapter I am not sure how this can be achieved.

Anybody has advice on best way to accomplish this either using C# or BizTalk? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you can run stored procedures which can call a CL or RPG program.

Another option is you can call CL command directly in SQL. Here is a generic method I use to do that if I don't expect any data back:

```
public static bool RunCmd(string cmdText, iDB2Connection cn)
{
    bool rc = true;

    // Construct a string which contains the call to QCMDEXC.
    string pgmParm = String.Format("CALL QSYS/QCMDEXC('{0}', {1})", 
                     cmdText.Replace("'", "''").Trim(), 
                     cmdText.Trim().Length.ToString("0000000000.00000"));

    using (cn)
    {
        using (iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command(pgmParm, cn))
        {
            try { cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); }
            catch { rc = false; }
        }
    }

    // Return success or failure
    return rc;
}
```

Since FTP might be your easiest option, [this short article](http://search400.techtarget.com/tip/Execute-remote-commands-using-FTP) should help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mike. Let me clarify, I do not have anything to do with DB2. I just need to call CL programs that reside on iSeries/OS400 machine. Is there a way to do that? One other approach that comes to mind is to have a batch file with FTP commands and using FTP invoke the CL jobs. The batch file then can be invoked from C#. What do you say?

Comment: You could [call a program via FTP](http://search400.techtarget.com/tip/Execute-remote-commands-using-FTP), but honestly, calling via SQL is easy. Why can't you connect to the IBM i? I am just curious.

Comment: I do not have DB2 Connection specs (is there an easy way to get them?) and also I need to FTP files to and from AS400 in addition to submitting jobs.

Comment: You use the iSeries Client Access driver. It needs to be installed on every server/workstation that the program would be used. The version also has to match. From there the connection string looks like [this](http://mikewills.me/blog/add-a-custom-ibm-i-library-list-to-a-c-application/). If you have to FTP files anyway, then you might as well just execute via FTP. In my previous comment I put a link on how to do that. I'll also add it to the answer.

Comment: I have FTP commands ready to submit the jobs. The question is more like how to execute those commands via C# or BizTalk. I do not see a library in C# that facilitates remote commands via FTP. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: I have never scripted FTP in C#. I am under the assumption that there is a library that does FTP stuff. Isn't there a method to just pass a custom command to the API?

Comment: The MSDN link that I have given in question points to FTP library in C#, I can see only limited FTP commands are exposed and there is no option to issue remote commands. I am not aware of any other library in C# provided with .NET.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't have the necessary licensing for the HIS server DB2 adapters as that would be the way to go.  Licensing info can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/biztalkr2adapters/thread/774fa114-4735-45e1-b906-2e17f8b9186e)

If you must use the FTP adpater you may be able to use:

SYSCMD CALL PGM(MYCLPGM) PARM('MYCLPARM')

instead of the QUOTE command you listed above